# Hyperlink to random HTML page

Tags: javascript, random, hyperlink

I have a selection of HTML pages (Lets say 30) and I want to have a randomise button, so that when the button is pressed, it displays one of the 30 pages randomly.

Ive found several scripts around the net that seem to do the trick, however they seem a bit 'hacky' and was wondering what the simplest, cleanest solution to this is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if var `arr` was your array you could get a random value using this :

```
var value = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
```

This generates a random number between 0 and the length of your array.

You can then navigate to that url ...

```
window.location = value;
```

### Update

Simple demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ESSAc/1/

Added a simple onclick attribute to a button :

```
<input type="button" onclick="runme()" value="Click Me!" />
```

to execute this function :

```
function runme() {
    var arr = ["http://www.bbc.co.uk/", "http://www.yahoo.com/", "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"];
    var value = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    alert("Would navigate to : " + value);
    // window.location = value;     // remove the comment at the beginning to actually navigate
}
```

Comment: Forgive me, my javascript is basic at best! Any chance of a quick demo?

Comment: that basically sums it up the random

Comment: @david sorry I don't follow your question ? or was it not a question ?

Comment: just a comment meaning your way is how i would of done random as well, which included a up vote

Comment: This seems to work, although I was wanting to open the random page when the user clicks a hyperlink? How would this be integrated?

Comment: @GrahamMcDonnell done ... that ok now ? P.S. Where should I send my invoice ?!?! :-)

Comment: Perfect Thanks! The cheque is in the post! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's 'hacky' or not, but I'd do it this way:

```
jQuery('#sumfin').onclick( function() {
    jQuery.get(
        'someurlthatreturnsjsonwitharandomurl.php',
        {},
        function (data) {
            window.location = data.url;
        },
        'json'
    );
}
```

Then just have an array of pages in a server-side script.

Comment: I dont see a jQuery tag on the question ....... an its **SO** simple in javascript ...

Comment: as above, my coding isnt great! Any chance of a quick demo?

Comment: @Graham, do you know any server-side languages?

Comment: @ManseUK jQuery is a pretty standard library, and provides a good Ajax wrapper. While this can be done in pure JavaScript, when you decide that you want 50 or 100 random URLs you start creating an issue where you're returning a lot of data when you really only need one record. Also, you may not want to provide the entire list of URLs to snooping power users.

Comment: @JonathanRich - I agree that jQuery is a good library ... however the question the OP asked and the answer you gave are the other ends of a scale .... he never mentioned jQuery, AJAX, Server Side or hiding form users ....

Comment: @ManseUK, that is true, but this isn't something I would recommend doing client-side simply because of the aforementioned issue with the inability to easily scale data. My implementation doesn't specifically require jQuery, however I prefer it when making Ajax calls.